# How to Delete and then Re-initialize Firebase App in android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm try to handle two databases of two different firebase projects. For this I have to first **Delete** newly initialized app and then have to **re-initialized** app.
For this purpose I'm trying to use but failed everytime.

```
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(context, firebaseOptions, "secondary").delete();
```

What should be used to Delete an secondary initialized firebase app? Here's below my code:

```
 boolean hasBeenInitialized = false;
    List<FirebaseApp> firebaseAppList = FirebaseApp.getApps(Charts.this);

    for (FirebaseApp app : firebaseAppList) {

        if (app.getName().equals("secondary")) {
            hasBeenInitialized = true;

        }
    }

    FirebaseOptions firebaseOptions = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            .setApiKey(apiKey)
            .setApplicationId(appId)
            .setDatabaseUrl(databaseLink)
            .build();

    if (!hasBeenInitialized) { //false
        firebaseApp = FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Charts.this, firebaseOptions, "secondary");

    } else {
        firebaseApp = FirebaseApp.getInstance("secondary");

        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Charts.this, firebaseOptions, "secondary").delete();
        firebaseApp = FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Charts.this, firebaseOptions, "secondary");

              }

    secondaryDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(firebaseApp);
```

`

Comment: "For this I have to first Delete newly initialized app and then have to re-initialized app" Why do you think that is needed? If you have an app that needs access to two Firebase projects, I would just expect to two `FirebaseApp` instances in the code. No need to delete either of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The Bugs

In your code, you find the secondary instance, but then immediately try to initialize it again throwing an error.

```
firebaseApp = FirebaseApp.getInstance("secondary");
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Charts.this, firebaseOptions, "secondary").delete(); // throws IllegalStateException
```

The fixed form of this would be:

```
firebaseApp = FirebaseApp.getInstance("secondary");
firebaseApp.delete();
```

Also, on the last line of your code, you try to get the `FirebaseApp` for the string value of `firebaseApp` not `"secondary"`

```
secondaryDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(firebaseApp);
```

The fixed from of this would be:

```
secondaryDatabase = firebaseApp;
// OR
secondaryDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("secondary");
```

### Fixed Code

Instead of storing the app instance as `firebaseApp` at all, just delete/use the instance directly.

```
List<FirebaseApp> firebaseAppList = FirebaseApp.getApps(Charts.this);

// Delete "secondary" if it exists
for (FirebaseApp app : firebaseAppList) {
    if (app.getName().equals("secondary")) {
        app.delete(); // found "secondary". Delete it
        break;
    }
}

// Build options object
FirebaseOptions firebaseOptions = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
        .setApiKey(apiKey)
        .setApplicationId(appId)
        .setDatabaseUrl(databaseLink)
        .build();

// Initialize
secondaryDatabase = FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Charts.this, firebaseOptions, "secondary");

// secondaryDatabase is now a FirebaseApp instance for the secondary database
```